# Export doesn't show correct amount of products

Tags: export

I'm trying to export all products in my catalog on Magento and I have over 1k products in the catalog. On the export section with 0 filters applied it only shows 77 records.

Running Magento ver 2.2.6

**Export Screen:**
Entity Type: Products
Export File Format: CSV
Fields Enclosure: Unchecked
Entity Attributes: Filter reset, 77 records found.

**Catalog > Products:**
Cleared all filters, 1157 records found.

How come the export doesn't produce 1157 records to be exported?

Answer (score 0):

The number you see there is not the number of products but the number of filters.

Don't worry, continue with the export.
If you want all your products don't select any filter.

[image]